# where are the Google app engine endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, endpoint

Im developing a simple app for android. I just created a few entity's, nothing but a poem filled in them by a string. Ive been using Google app engine and it works in my browser just fine, deployed my little project. I want to use retrofit lib to grab the list of entity's i made in probably a simple for loop to an object class i make for them, however how do I define my endpoints! I cant seem to find them. new at this networking stuff but i'm trying very hard.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae
Looks like I need to actually create an app linked to the Google a engine.
Is this the only way? What if i had a team who needed to access the end points on an iphone app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having an android app which was not created using `appengine connected app` option, then you can still create the app engine code for it by right clicking and choosing the options `Google->Generate App Engine Backend` . After modifying your backend code, you can generate the client library for this backend by right clicking and choosing option `Google->Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library` ,then deploy it to app engine and start accessing the endpoints from the android app.

If you are already having an android app and app engine code which are not yet connected, then you need to modify your backend code to include endpoint methods by following this [tictactoe sample backend with endpoints](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java) . After doing this, you need to generate the android client lib using command line and import it to your android app to start accessing the endpoints. Follow this [tictactoe sample android app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android) to understand how to call endpoints and get and send data to the same.

In the future if you want to access the same endpoints from an iOS app, you wont need any modification in your backend with cloud endpoints and just need to create a client lib for iOS by following the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios). You can see the [sample tictactoe app for iOS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-ios) to understand how to handle endpoints in iOS